# How to get the right line and position in ANTLR 4 when using the notifyErrorListeners(String msg) function in the Listener?

Tags: java, antlr4

I would like to create my own error listener instead of the default ANTLR 4 error listener,and I'm using the notifyErrorListeners(String msg) function but ANTLR doesn't give me the right line and position of the error , here is my code.

```
grammar DSL;
main: 'begin' assign* println* 'end';
assign: name = ID '=' value= (STRING | INTEGER);
println: 'println' value  = ID;

fragment LETTER : [A-Za-z];
fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
ID : LETTER+; // match identifiers 
/* data types */
STRING : '"' ( ~ '"' )* '"' ; // match string content
INTEGER: DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT+)*;
LINE_COMMENT: '#' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' { skip(); };
WS  :  ( ' '|'\t')+ { skip(); };
```

```
public class CustomError extends BaseErrorListener {
    @Override
    public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine,
            String msg, RecognitionException e) {
        System.out.println("line = " + line + ",position = " + charPositionInLine + ",msg = " + msg);
    }
}
```

```
@Override
    public void enterAssign(DSLParser.AssignContext ctx) {
        String name = ctx.name.getText();
        String value = ctx.value.getText().replace("\"", "");
        if (tmp_variables.containsKey(name)) {
            // How can I get the correct line and position of the error from assignContext ?
            dslParser.notifyErrorListeners("duplicate local variable");
        } else {
            tmp_variables.put(name, value);
        }
    }
```

So for example if my input is like so .

```
begin

name = "name"
name = "name2"
println name

end
```

ANTLR must have an output as follows.

```
line = 4,position = 0,msg = duplicate local variable
```

but the output is the following.

```
line = 7,position = 3,msg = duplicate local variable
```

In every execution , the output is always the same,(7 corresponds to the last line and 3 to the last character). so why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

NotifyErrorListeners is for syntax errors, not for reporting semantic errors that are done in the tree walker. But, if you look at the source of the runtime, you will see that notifyErrorListeners passes CurrentToken to an inner method. CurrentToken has nothing to do with the tree, and the current tree node isn't even passed to the notify method. At the time you call notifyErrorListeners, CurrentToken is positioned at the end of file (i.e., it parsed correctly), which is at line 7. That's why you see what you see. You're going to want to write out your own error message in your listener. You may want to note the error is at the value, not the line/col of the first token of the subtree AssignContext. Also, you should be consistent by using "-> skip" throughout your grammar. You have two action blocks "{ skip(); }", which isn't target language independent.